# Execute PHP Code

Tags: php, refresh, html

Is it somehow possible to execute a PHP Website code without the need to have the Website open.  Something like a intern webbrowser the refreshes itselfs.
Or is the any other way like a repeating sheduler the executes the Code every 10 seconds.

Comment: try or serach cron job

Comment: php can be executed from the command line. it's not a "web-only" language...

Comment: You mean like a headless browser, or just a PHP script and crontab? ... both are possible, depends on what you want to do. If it's to execute a simple script every 10 seconds, crontab is probably what you're after. Either way: voted to close as off-topic for SO, as this is not a specific code-related issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use cron to run any code on a repeating basis

Add the following to your crontab which will run every minute to try it out

```
* * * * * /path/to/php /var/www/html/a.php
```

Comment: Oh i didnt think about cron. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkBaker: My mistake, forgot cron only works down to the minute...

Answer (score 0):

You can use cron job for repeating action otherwise you can also use event scheduler

**Cron job**
You can set a cron job from Cpanel -> Cron tab -> add file name

**Event scheduler**
you can set a event scheduler from mysql

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your code, so the OP can learn from it.